# How can I automatically update a property of an object in an array when another property of the same object is updated?

Tags: vue.js

My model looks like this:

```js
export default {
   data() {
      return {
         ...
         salesOrder: {
            ...
            line_items: [{
               status: 'saved',
               item_number: 1,
               description: 'The first line item'
               cost: 458.00,
               quantity: 2
            }, {
               status: 'saved',
               item_number: 2,
               description: 'The second line item'
               cost: 0.589,
               quantity: 3
            }]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And it's used to generate a UI that looks like this:
[image]

I would like to update the `status` field whenever the `description`, `quantity`, or `cost` fields change on the same line item so that my UI would look like this:
[image]

The problem is, it doesn't look like there's any way to watch properties of an object inside an array.

I can create a computed property for the array, and watch that, but then I get the **entire array** as the `val` and `newVal` params:

```js
{
   computed: {
      lineItems() {
         return this.salesOrder.line_items;
      }
   },
   watch: {
      lineItems() {
         handler(val, newVal) {
            // val and newVal are the whole array
         },
         deep: true
      }
   }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How about attaching an event handler (i.e. `onchange` which should translate to `@change`) on the input fields for `Description`, `Quantity` and `Unit Price` so that when the value has been changed, you can then change the status for the corresponding row record?

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I'll give it a shot

Comment: FYI, the `val` and `newVal` in watcher functions are always the same for objects and arrays - because they are stored by reference and not duplicated: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch